# Div tags not tightly fit? Invisible padding?

Tags: html, css

I have a page consisting of inline-block divs that span horizontally off of the screen.

Codepen here:
http://codepen.io/gosusheep/pen/GJEPEV `.`

Processed output here: http://s.codepen.io/gosusheep/debug/GJEPEV `.`

Inside the #slider div, there are several .slide-content divs. Each .slide-content takes up the entire window size. When scrolling, it should move to the next page.

I would like to have the .slide-content divs to fit right up next to each other. Instead, according to Chrome's element inspector, there is a small spacing between each div.

Let's say the window size is 1000. I would want the first div at x:0, the 2nd at x:1000, and so on. That way, if I do $(window).scrollLeft(1000), it scrolls to have the 2nd div right smack in the center.

But when I put a border around the divs to see why the spacing is off, there's an unwanted space between them.

Anyone know why?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have white space between the divs (a line break). When you treat them as inline blocks, then this translates to a space character, just as if you have white space between, say, two images. I think that placing the </div><div> immediately after one another will fix this.

Comment: This is one of the weird quirks of HTML: whitespace is *sometimes* significant. Good catch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I think you might be right, but I have been unable to do so easily. I am using HAML to process a ruby array.

I will try to remove the HTML generation in JavaScript and see if I can get it done there.

Comment: There are alternativates if you can change the HTML. See https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

As per vals link (see comment in Stephen Poley's answer) to CSS-Tricks suggested, I decided to go the route that modified CSS instead of HTML. But this is only because I use HAML to generate my HTML. I would've probably removed the whitespace instead had I the option.

```
div.container{
  font-size: 0;
}

div.content{
  font-size: 16px; /*my default */
}
```